# One word for the phrase "depends on the context"

Tags: single-word-requests

When asked about one's belief/opinion on an idea/issue, instead of answering with the cliché "it depends on the context", what word would be appropriate?

Comment: *context-dependent* ?

Comment: @ermanen - that's what I initially went for, then I found this (and decided to keep it simple): *Context-dependent memory refers to improved recall of specific episodes or information when the context present at encoding and retrieval are the same. One particularly common example of context-dependence at work occurs when an individual has lost an item (e.g. lost car keys) in an unknown location.* Wikipedia

Comment: @LittleEva: Yes I found it too but it depends on the context. Or context-dependent? :)

Comment: Ha-ha! Good one, ermanen.

Answer (score 5):

Possibly you're looking for,

> [**contextual**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/contextual+definition) *noun*, Logic, Philosophy **1**. definition of a word or symbol by explaining the meaning of the phrase or statement in which it occurs. see, Dictionary.com

And if you're game for a two-word submission, you might like,

> [Context Dependence](http://userwww.sfsu.edu/kbach/Bach.ContextDependence.pdf) by Kent Bach
>
> All sorts of things are context-dependent in one way or another. What it is appropriate to wear, to give, or to reveal depends on the context. Whether or not it is all right to lie, harm, or even kill depends on the context. If you google the phrase ‘**depends on the context**’, you’ll get several hundred million results. This chapter aims to narrow that down. In this context the topic is context dependence in language and its use.

But of course, that depends ...

Comment: So the answer to the hypothetical question (about one's opinion) would be: "it's contextualized"? That makes me think of it as meaning something else than intended (it has been contextualized) but maybe that's my use of the word being too narrow. I can't think of a better one.

Comment: Oh, thanks. That's inadvertent, of course I intended "contextual"! :-)

Comment: Ah yes. Much better. I'd +1 that

Comment: Good lookin' out, Avon.

Comment: @LittleEva - Thanks. The chapter is insightful and I really liked it. 'Context dependent' and 'context sensitive' do sound more concise but (as the chapter suggests) one may want use them with care and determine the context first. Makes a difference to clarity in communication.

Comment: Sure, C2R. Glad you liked it. "Everything is context" = Einstein's *General Relativity*.

Comment: Also, maybe try "deictic" (adjective form of "deixis").